# mkdir - create directory (with ":" in its name) does not work in specific directory, works in others

Tags: raspbian, ext4, escape-characters, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory for a movie on my Plex media server and ran into a strange issue. When I try to make a directory with the movie name ("Borat: Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan"), I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Plex/Movies $ mkdir "Borat: Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Borat: Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan’: Invalid argument
```

I know that colon (`:`) is a special character, and this command works without the colon. What I cannot explain is why the command works with the colon if I run it in different paths. For example, it worked in:

1. `/media/pi`
2. `/home/pi`
3. `/tmp`

I thought it might be because of a path length limit, but that was not the case. Any other ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What type of filesystem is the `/media/pi/Plex/Movies` directory mounted on?

Comment: `:` marks [NTFS alternate data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_stream_(ADS)), hence isn't valid in file names there, so it's conceivable it would fail on NTFS.

Comment: @Kusalananda I completely forgot that ```/media/pi/plex``` is external storage, using exFAT... I assume exFAT is like NTFS when it comes to colons.

Comment: NTFS doesn't prevent me creating items with colons - in Cygwin on Windows (with NTFS) I can `mkdir 'a:b'` and it happily creates the directory for me. (In Windows Explorer, however, the same directory is represented as `a·b`.)